# Real time Querying on Real-time Data

Tags: mongodb, real-time, apache-kafka

I have data flowing from Kafka into MongoDB real-time. This is just raw data and various APIs are served using this data in real time.

The APIs respond using aggregation queries. However when data to be aggregated is large, the response time of the API is too high.

What technology or methodology can I adopt to achieve low latency for API responses?

**Current Approach**

I am aggregating data using *Spark Streaming* based on the type of queries made by the API. This has reduced the API response time, but changes in queries take a long time to be reflected in API results as the whole data needs to be aggregated based on the new type of queries. But this leads to significant downtime. Is this the right approach. If yes, how can I lessen the downtime.

Comment: Caching works well if the requests are repeated often enough and the data doesn't have to be as fresh as the dew on a spring morning.

Comment: The data needs to be fresh and available even at the millisecond level.

Comment: Then there isn't much you can do. If you absolutely *must* have new data and you absolutely *must* aggregate large amounts of data, this is the only way.  I would suggest you do some sort of background analysis on the data for quick access, but the data wouldn't be fresh.  You could do caching, but again, the data wouldn't be fresh.  You could do sampling of the data to reduce the workload, but then your results wouldn't be accurate.  Speed / accuracy / memory -> pick two.

Comment: @Neil: I have added my current approach in which I chose speed and accuracy. But downtime seems to be an issue.

Comment: A speed and accuracy approach could be to keep an updated model in memory of aggregate data as your database is updated.  Then you need not perform an analysis on the data, because your memory model is already accurate.  However if you do it this way, you'd need to have a preload phase before you start serving requests that restores that memory model from the database.  Also, you'd need to be very careful not to use up all the memory and have a plan for if and when you do.

Comment: Rather than keeping the aggregated data in-memory wouldn't it be better to keep it in a NoSQL distributed database. The response time would be good(in order of ms, which is fine for our case) and the system could also scale when data size increases. However I did not get what you meant by the **preload phase**.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70661/discussion-between-nishant-kumar-and-neil).

Comment: MongoDB is already a no SQL database, is it not?  Aren't we assuming that the current system is too slow?  The preload phase is what happens when a program that heavily basis its aggregate info on what it has in memory must do before servicing requests.  Otherwise memory is empty when program starts.

Comment: Yes Mongo is a NoSql DB but that's not what is slow. What is slow is aggregating data real time for every API request. If we aggregrate this data real time using streaming services like Spark, the response time issue is solved. However changes in query has a lot of downtime as the data needs to be aggregated in a particular format again on the basis of the query.

Comment: Ok, so use the memory solution.  If I need the sum of numbers on the database for the last hour, keep a running tally in memory.  Save the information in the database just the same, but keep the sum.  Then when someone asks for it, you simply give it to them.  Perform the analysis and aggregation as the data comes in, in other words.

Comment: With Spark Streaming, we are doing the same. Talking about the example you mentioned: **the sum of numbers from last hour**. So, every hour we also would have to subtract points from the past hour in addition to adding incoming points. This is mangable with a particular architecture design. But the problem here is what happens if the API query changes to **sum of numbers from past 10 mins**. This would mean that we have to run the aggregation again, which would be a significant downtime for the API. The API would be live again when all the aggregations are done. How to avoid this downtime?

Comment: You can still keep all the information you require in memory, if memory is not an issue.  Hold only time and amount over the past hour ordered by a timestamp.  To find sum over last 10 minutes, search backwards until you reach a timestamp older than 10 minutes and add everything else up.

Comment: The real problem is much more complex and involves filters and group by on multiple fields. However Thanks!!

Comment: Hopefully you'll agree that there isn't nearly enough information for me to know what you need, so you'll forgive me for an incomplete solution.

Comment: Yes!! Let me find a way to sample my data and post an updated question.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you you have a working system to serve responses to query “refreshes” but look for a way to be fast when a new “type” of query arrives. Unless you can predict what is to come then your only option is to add raw computing power. If you can predict some likely queries you may pre-populate the reply pipeline. Maybe you could have an Option for clients to warn what they will start requesting soon so preparation can start early giving a perceived better performance.

Comment: Sorry meant for this to be a comment not a reply but cannot delete it.